# Trying to do a matching between a value from an object of objects to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do a matching between an object of objects (A) and an array of objects (B).

Each object in the object of objects has a PID.  Each object in the array of objects has a PID.  I am trying to match A and B so I can get the occupation from A, and then append the occupation to each object in B.  So, I am trying to get PID and Occupation into one.  Can this even be done?

So, here's what A might look like:

```
{
  emp1: {
    PID: 2430
    Occupation: Welder
  },
  emp2: {
    PID: 432,
    Occupation: Electrician
  }
}
```

and B:

```
[
  {
    PID: 432
  },
  {
    PID: 2430
  }
]
```

Can this be easily done using something like lodash library?

Comment: A is an invalid JSON format

Comment: @Dalorzo and who talked 'bout json? its still a valid JS Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run a loop inside loop to match elements from B to A (or other way round) which is quite expensive. It would have been much easier if you could change structure of, let's say, A.

```
A = {
    2430: {
        name: "John",
        occupation: "Welder"
    },
    432: {
        name: "John",
        occupation: "Electrician"
    }
}
```

Then you can access data in `A` like this: `A[2430]`

Then your code could look like that:

```
B = B.map(function(el) {
    return {
        PID: el.PID,
        occupation: A[el.PID].occupation
    }
});
console.log(B);
```

So you have just one loop. Also you benefit from much faster access to data from `A` in the future.